# Perl Rar a whole folder

Tags: perl, directory, rar

I want to rar a whole folder with Perl and [`Archive::Rar`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive%3a%3aRar). For example the folder `/root/pictures`.

I have found only a way to rar single files.

I tried to find all files in the folder and rar them, but then I always have the whole path sticking to them (`/root/pictures`) in the rar archive.

I want only the `/pictures` folder plus its contents. Is that possible?

Comment: do you mean path instead of pack?

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure of the files stored in the archive will be the same as the file names that you pass to the `Add` method. (Although you can add them without any containing folder at all using the `-excludepaths` option.)

If you `chdir` to the `\root` directory before adding the files to the archive, and specify all your files as `pictures\file1.jpg` etc. then the result should be as you want.

Something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Rar;

use autodie;

chdir '\root';

my $rar = Archive::Rar->new(-archive => 'pictures.rar');

$rar->Add(-files => [ glob 'pictures\*' ]);
```

Clearly you could add a path to the rar file name if you want the archive stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to get a list of files from defined directory:

```
use File::Find;

my @content;
find( \&wanted, '/some/path');

sub wanted {
  push @content, $File::Find::name;
  return;
}
```

After that you may use the Archive::Rar to pack it.

```
use Archive::Rar;
my $rar = Archive::Rar->new();
$rar->Add(
       -size => $size_of_parts,
       -archive => $archive_filename,
       -files => \@content,
);
```